# How to detect Jenkins multibranch branch or tag

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks, artifactory

I had setup a multibranch pipeline with Git webhook for branch and tag. It does discovery when new tag is created.

However, I wanted to determine if the current execution is base off a branch or a tag to determine action such as publishing up to artifactory.

E.g. If build is for a tag, and environment is SIT, I will publish up to Artifactory upon build and test success.

Any idea how to check in multibranch pipeline if the current execution is for branch or tag?

Answer (score 2):

There is a part of my Jenkinsfile for differ branches from tags:

```
environment {
GIT_BRANCH_OR_TAG = sh(returnStdout: true, script:
'''\
     #!/bin/bash -e
     GIT_REMOTE=$(git remote)
     if git rev-parse --verify -q refs/remotes/${GIT_REMOTE}/${GIT_BRANCH}^{} | grep -q ${GIT_COMMIT}
       then echo branch
       exit 0
     elif git rev-parse --verify -q refs/tags/${GIT_BRANCH}^{} | grep -q ${GIT_COMMIT}
       then echo tag
       exit 0
     else echo unknown
       exit 0
     fi
'''.stripIndent()).trim()
}
```

If you will try to use `git show-ref` instead `git rev-parse` with `^{}` you could get the situation, when checked out commit hash sum is different with tag object.
There example:

```
[17:20:17] user@host:/tmp/dummy-git/ 
>ѳ> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/dummy-git/.git/
[17:20:21] user@host:/tmp/dummy-git/ (master|✔)
>±> touch file        
[17:20:31] user@host:/tmp/dummy-git/ (master|…)
>±> git add file 
[17:20:53] user@host:/tmp/dummy-git/ (master|●1)
>±> git commit -m 'dummy commit'
[master (root-commit) 0835e70] dummy commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file
[17:21:04] user@host:/tmp/dummy-git/ (master|✔)
>±> git tag -m 'dummy annotation' with-annotation
[17:21:40] user@host:/tmp/dummy-git/ (master|✔)
>±> git tag without-annotation                  
[17:21:51] user@host:/tmp/dummy-git/ (master|✔)
>±> git show-ref
0835e706a64f8fd7f7cc8eec904eb527925ebf22 refs/heads/master
b75da5a999f358a390b403136904f4a974787da1 refs/tags/with-annotation
0835e706a64f8fd7f7cc8eec904eb527925ebf22 refs/tags/without-annotation
[17:21:59] user@host:/tmp/dummy-git/ (master|✔)
>±> git show with-annotation  
tag with-annotation
Tagger: user <user@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 13 17:21:36 2018 +0100

dummy annotation

commit 0835e706a64f8fd7f7cc8eec904eb527925ebf22 (HEAD -> master, tag: without-annotation, tag: with-annotation)
Author: user <user@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 13 17:21:04 2018 +0100

    dummy commit

diff --git a/file b/file
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
[17:22:21] user@host:/tmp/dummy-git/ (master|✔)
>±> git show without-annotation
commit 0835e706a64f8fd7f7cc8eec904eb527925ebf22 (HEAD -> master, tag: without-annotation, tag: with-annotation)
Author: user <user@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 13 17:21:04 2018 +0100

    dummy commit

diff --git a/file b/file
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
[17:22:23] user@host:/tmp/dummy-git/ (master|✔)
>±> git rev-parse refs/tags/with-annotation^{}
0835e706a64f8fd7f7cc8eec904eb527925ebf22
[17:22:56] user@host:/tmp/dummy-git/ (master|✔)
>±> git rev-parse refs/tags/with-annotation   
b75da5a999f358a390b403136904f4a974787da1
```

Comment: Didnt know its so difficult to detect if its a tag. Likely i may enforce the tag to contain certain keyword instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable GIT_BRANCH in your Jenkinsfile for that. Or, in your stage, do it like this:

```
...
stage("Publish to Artifactory") {
  when {
    branch("master")
  }
  ...
}
...
```

Regarding tags, I recommend let Jenkins do the tagging at the end of a successful publishing. Because if you do the tagging by yourself and trigger Jenkins, you assume that your build is going to be successful. Your tag build can fail, even if the very same build succeeded before, e.g. when your Artifactory is down. Then you would have to move around the tags which is not nice.

Try to implement your release pipeline, at the end of the pipeline when the Artifact has been published, tag the successful build like this (disclaimer: this is untested):

```
success {
   script {
       if (env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ /release\/.+/) {
         def tag = ...
         sh "git tag ${tag}"
         sh "git push --tags"
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I wanted tag to be more controlled n only happen after SIT tag build in pipeline. But could not really get the tag name. The branch name does not contain any tag or release related terms.